# Symfony skeleton project server callback / wrongly styled

Tags: symfony, server

I have installed all the newest versions of all software of Symfony and then i copy the Symfony website skeleton (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) or the Symfony demo for that matter. Everything works fine so far, and i start to use the development local server provided by Symfony using

```
$ symfony serve
```

The problem with the output of https://localhost:8000 is that the CSS apparently is not getting loaded, it has the Times New Roman font and some other styles are missing. What stranger is; during the loading of the page the CSS actually *is*  present (different font, nice stylings). The log of the Symfony server is

```
symfony serve
Apr 18 10:02:59 |INFO | PHP    listening path="C:\\PHP\\php-cgi.exe" php="7.3.4" port=53259
Apr 18 10:02:59 |DEBUG| PHP    started

[OK] Web server listening on https://127.0.0.1:8000 (PHP CGI 7.3.4)


Apr 18 08:03:02 |INFO | REQUES Matched route "homepage". method="GET" request_uriApr 18 10:03:02 |INFO | =ERVERSGET  (302)   ipi"::1" =oute="::1"="::1" "::1"="::1" route_parametersroute_parameters={"_controller":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\TemplateController::templateAction","_locale":"en","_route":"homepage","template":"default/homepage.html.twig"}
Apr 18 08:03:02 |INFO | SECURI Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
Apr 18 08:03:03 |INFO | REQUES Matched route "homepage". method="GET" request_uri="https://localhost:8000/nl" route="homepage" route_parameters={"_controller":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\TemplateController::templateAction","_locale":"nl","_route":"homepage","template":"default/homepage.html.twig"}
Apr 18 08:03:03 |INFO | SECURI Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
Apr 18 10:03:03 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) /nl
Apr 18 08:03:03 |INFO | REQUES Matched route "_wdt". method="GET" request_uri="https://localhost:8000/_wdt/d97f3f" route="_wdt" route_parameters={"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","_route":"_wdt","token":"d97f3f"}
Apr 18 10:03:04 |ERROR| SERVER issue with server callback error="EOF"
Apr 18 10:03:04 |INFO | SERVER GET  (200) /_wdt/d97f3f ip="::1"
```

So the only error i receive is SERVER issue with server callback error="EOF"

When i go into the HTML code and i remove this div

```
<div id="sfwdtd97f3f" class="sf-toolbar sf-display-none" data-sfurl="/_wdt/d97f3f" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

The page works fine and is well formatted. So i am starting to think it is caused by some kind toolbar, but i have everything installed newly, including symfony/profiler-pack. Fyi, i do not see any kind of toolbar in my browser.

Since i am just starting with Symfony, i'd like everything to work perfectly, and that is not the case now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem right but you can desactivate it in config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml and set toolbar to false.

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

[Edit]

Javier Cuervas has the right answer

Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, it's happening since upgrading version to 4.4.4 of symfony server.
I can run the server with "bin/console server:run" command and the problem is gone